# Creating new fromList from fromList with "keys"

Tags: haskell

Trying to work out a solution to this problem..

Let's say I have x = fromList[("a", 1), ("b", 2), ("c", 3)]

And have a list ["a", "a", "b", "c" , "c"]

How would I think about producing something like..

Map.fromList[("a", 2), ("b", 2), ("c", 6)]

Any help leading in the right direction would be greatly appreciated

Comment: This is a little confusing, but is your intention that the counts in the final map should match the product of the counts in map `x` and the number of times the key appears in the source list?  So, `"c"` ends up as 6 because it's 3 (from `x`) times the 2 copies of `"c"` in the input list `["a","a","b","c","c"]`?

Answer (score 2):

I'm starting from the assumption in [K. A. Buhr's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63331461/creating-new-fromlist-from-fromlist-with-keys#comment111987643_63331461) that you want to obtain the product of the counts in the original hash and the hash originating from the input list.

For this we need a function `occurrences` which transforms a list of strings into a hash from string to number of occurrences.  This can easily be done using the [`insertWith`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/containers-0.6.3.1/docs/Data-Map-Internal.html#v:insertWith) function, which combines a the value to be inserted with the stored values using the given operation if a stored value exists and otherwise just inserts.

To multiply the occurrences with the existing hash, we use the [`unionWith`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/containers-0.6.3.1/docs/Data-Map-Internal.html#v:unionWith) function which works in a similar way as `insertWith` in the sense that it forms the union using a given operation if the element exists in both hashes and otherwise just inserts.

```
{-# OPTIONS_GHC -Wall #-}

import Data.Map

x :: Map String Int
x = fromList [("a", 1), ("b", 2), ("c", 3)]

occurrences :: Ord k => [k] -> Map k Int
occurrences l = aux l empty
  where
    aux [] h = h
    aux (a:as) h = aux as $ insertWith (+) a 1 h

main ::  IO ()
main = print $ unionWith (*) x $ occurrences ["a", "a", "b", "c", "c"]
```

[Live example on Wandbox](https://wandbox.org/permlink/hQFInB9FZ1nNyOJa)

Comment: `occurrences` can be simplified a bit: ``occurrences = Map.fromListWith (+) . fmap (, 1)``. You *could* use `Sum` here—and `Product` for the multiplication—but for this small example it’s not really worthwhile to abstract, particularly since you have to use `unionWith (<>)` because of `Map`’s biased `Semigroup` instance.

Comment: Good answer.  My only comment: it's possible that `intersectionWith` should be used in place of `unionWith`, if the desire is that a key appearing in only one input should be left out of the answer (since technically the resulting product is zero).

Comment: @K.A.Buhr I guess we'll never know what OP really wants to do.